# Inherited methods with tighter constraints?

Tags: c#, inheritance

Suppose I have the following:

```
class EntityContainer : Container { }
class EntityComponent : Component { }
```

Container has two methods for adding new components to the container, those being:

```
Add(IComponent component)
Add(IComponent component, string name)
```

However, suppose I want my `EntityContainer` class to take **only** `EntityComponent` objects, instead of anything that implements `IComponent`.

At first, I thought I could simply hide or override the base class's `Add()` methods, but it seems that the signature has to match *exactly*. What then, is the best way to do this?

Comment: Is it possible to make the base class generic?

Comment: In your `Add` methods, fail if the type passed is incompatible: `if( !(component is EntityContainer) ) throw new InvalidArgumentException("component");`. Once a class passes, you can cast it to the expected type: `var c = component as EntityContainer;` and use that from there as if you had received it directly.

Comment: These are more specific implementations of the default System.ComponentModel.Component and .Container, so I'm leaning towards "no".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Overriding' the Add method so it receives a more specific type would not fulfill the contract that your interface implies.

You say that the Container interface has these methods:

```
void Add(IComponent component);
void Add(IComponent component, string name);
```

But you want to allow only EntityContainer instances (which implement IComponent), so basically you want this:

```
void Add(EntityComponent component);
void Add(EntityComponent component, string name);
```

You can't implement (not even semantically) the Container interface like this, because in your interface you are saying that you can add any element that implements IComponent. You're changing the original contract!

As Morten pointed in the comments, you could do something like this:

```
class EntityContainer : Container { 
   void Add(IComponent component) {
       var entityComponent = component as EntityComponent;
       if(entityComponent == null)
          throw new InvalidOperationException("Can only add EntityComponent instances");
       // Actual add...
   }
   // Other methods..
}
```

But I would suggest you to not do that. Breaking the contract that the interface implies should be the exception, not the rule. Also, if you do that, you couldn't know what the Container really expects until runtime. This is not an intuitive behavior, and it will most likely cause subtle problems. If you want to accept only a specific type of components, you could use generics. By this way, not only you can apply the constraints you want, you will also gain strong-typing, and your intention will be clearer. It would look like these:

```
interface Container<T> where T : IComponent {
   void Add(T component);
   void Add(T component, string name);
}
```

It means that your container will hold the elements of the specified type, but it should implement (or extend, if it's a class) the interface IComponent. So you can't create a `Container<Object>`, because it does not implement IComponent.

Your EntityContainer would look like this:

```
class EntityContainer : Container<EntityComponent> { 
   void Add(EntityComponent component) {
       // Actual add...
   }
   // Other methods..
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Covariance of *in* parameters breaks the type system. Consider this:

```
void f(Container c) { c.Add(new NonEntityComponent); }
⋮
var ec = new EntityContainer();
f(ec);
```

Nothing in the type system can prevent this. The fact the derived method in `EntityContainer` is declared as `Add(EntityComponent ec)` doesn't help because `f()` has never heard of `EntityContainer`.

Allowing a covariant parameter would create situations that break the type system, e.g., `EntityContainer.Add()` being passed a `NonEntityComponent` and treating it as if it were an `EntityComponent`.

Some forms of variance could be implemented coherently: covariant return types (C++ has these), covariant out parameters, and contravariant *in* parameters. For reasons I'm not privy to, these weren't implemented. Actually, contravariant parameters would be a bit silly, IMO, so I'd be surprised to see them make an appearance.